# Scala 2.9 won't run HelloWorld on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: scala, exception, runtime, ubuntu-12.04, scala-2.9

This one should be simple, but I can't figure it out myself.

I have Scala 2.9.1 installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 system.

The file is `helloworld.scala`:

```
object HelloWorld{
        def main(args:Array[String]){
                println("Hello, World!")
        }
}
```

scalac helloworld works totally fine without issue. Then scala HelloWorld gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: HelloWorld
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

I've seen this question several times on forums but the poster is usually just mixing the class name and the file name so they would be trying scala helloworld, this is not what I'm doing (right?) but I get the same error.

### Edit

`scala -classpath ./ HelloWorld` works fine. So it's a classpath problem.

Comment: you should really look into sbt: put your sources in . and your jars in lib, then just run `sbt run`

Comment: sbt looks good, just had a quick play. But if I have several projects all requiring the same library, I end up with that library copied into the lib folder for every project? Whereas the classpath should be set up such that a common library is always referenced and for scala and java etc ??

Comment: the lib folder is just one way of doing things. the canonical way is to reference the dependency in your build.sbt and sbt will download it from a repository and store it in a local cache that is shared with all projects. It's the same mechanism maven uses.

Comment: What if you rename the object to HelloNameThatIsDefinitelyUnique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and got exactly the same. Then I cleared my classpath thus:

```
$ CLASSPATH=
```

and all worked.

Comment: yes, I've just noticed that if I run scala -classpath ./ HelloWorld it runs fine. The problem is that my classpath appends /bin/boportalcso.jar which is a concurrent programming library for scala which i intend to use, if I clear my classpath, this library won't be located right?

Comment: After further checking, let me explain why this doesn't really solve the problem. I need (for future programs, here one called csotext.scala which compiles to Race.class) ~/bin/biportaltcso.jar appended to the classpath. At the moment to compile I do CLASSPATH=~/bin/biportaltcso.jar:$CLASSPATH then scalac csotest.scala then CLASSPATH=      then scala Race    Obviously this is a pain. So in reality I'll keep the classpath with the librrary appended and just type scala -classpath ./ Race everytime. This isn't ideal either but I don't really know enough about how the classpath works to fix this.

Comment: so just put the jar and . on the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Ubuntu and testing with your example I can confirm that:

```
scala HelloWorld.scala
```

will run the file successfully as a Scala script. And:

```
scalac HelloWorld.scala
```

will create the class files.

But, running:

```
scala HelloWorld.class
```

will give the error you are getting.

However, if you are running

```
scala HelloWorld
```

in the directory that has the class file in it, then the program should execute without a problem.

Comment: Thanks, this may be helpful to others, but it's not the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked, but since you have many dependencies, it would be better to use sbt and let *it* worry about classpaths.

Comment: This is actually what i'm using now, Kim Stebel suggested it above. However as far as I can tell every project that requires dependency X, need X.jar in it's own lib folder, whereas if the classpath was behaving, it would only need to be added to the classpath once and then any project could use this library.